# can't assign value to/from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I thought of myself that I'm decently experienced in creating a vba code but this supposedly simple task is devastatingly hard... or is it? I'm trying to create several documents with different names and in each there would be difference in only two cells. Problem is that I can't even get past the value change.

I know there are different ways to achieve this and I sort of got them right to get what I needed. My problem is - I have absolutely no idea why the code below doesn't work. The error I get is "Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and highlited is the first row in for loop

```
"Sheets("List1").Range("C2") = Sheets("výroba").Range(Cells(row, 1)).Value
```

Can anyone tell whats the problem?

Code:

```
Sub pal()

Dim rows_total As Integer
Dim row As Integer



rows_total = Application.CountA(Worksheets("výroba").Range("A:A"))


For row = 1 To rows_total

Sheets("List1").Range("C2") = Sheets("výroba").Range(Cells(row, 1)).Value

Sheets("List1").Range("E2") = Sheets("výroba").Range(Cells(row, 2)).Value

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Úkoláky pokov\výroba\" & Worksheets("výroba").Range(Cells(row, 2)).Value & ".xlsx"

Next row


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use `Sheets("výroba").Range(Cells(row, 1)).Value`?

Just use `Sheets("výroba").Cells(row, 1).Value` instead